# How to format output video/audio name with youtube-dl embed?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm writing a python script that downloads videos from a URL using youtube-dl. Here's the code:

```
def downloadVideos(videoURL):
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestvideo,bestaudio',
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([videoURL])
```

The above method downloads an mp4 file for the video and a m4a file for the audio. The only thing is, the names for the files are some random strings. How can I give a custom name for the output files? And is it possible to put these in a specific folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def downloadVideos(videoURL):
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestvideo,bestaudio',
        'outtmpl': 'You can enter your text here -%(title)s.%(ext)s'
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([videoURL])
```

You need to put outtmpl option within ydl_opts. You can type anything you want inside it. (title) will give you title of the video, (ext) is of course the extension of it. You can define output path as well. So final code should look like this :

```
def downloadVideos(videoURL):
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestvideo,bestaudio',
        'outtmpl': 'path/to/folder/Write Something here - %(title)s.%(ext)s'
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([videoURL])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to set custom names to files you download:

```
#Import the module to download videos
import youtube_dl

#Create a function to save downloaded videos
def downloadVideos(videoURL):
    #Video file location and name
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestvideo,bestaudio',
        'outtmpl': '/your_path/to/your_folder/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    }
   
    #Download the video
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([videoURL])
```

The outtmpl parameter is used to save the file in a specific folder with custom name and extension.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the YT-DLP for a personal project involving Twitch Clips and since I had quite some trouble working with the API of this tool, I managed to rename and save the downloaded files to another directory using the function bellow:

```
def download_clip(slug: str):
    url = f'https://clips.twitch.tv/{slug}'
        ydl_opts = {
            'quiet': True,
            'verbose': False,
            'format': 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best',
            'outtmpl': f'/clips/{slug}.%(ext)s' # downloads clips to the clips subfolder using the slug as filename.
        }
        try:
            with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([url])
        except:
            print('Not working..')
```

I hope it help!